# Why does git clean -dX not remove my ignored directory?

Tags: git, gitignore, git-clean

I would like git to clean up all **untracked** files that I have **ignored**.

I thought that `git clean -dX` was the obvious solution, but it does nothing:

```
# Set up test directory
mkdir git-test && cd git-test
git init && touch x && git add x && git commit -m Initial

mkdir -p folder1/folder2/
touch    folder1/folder2/file

echo "folder2/" >> .gitignore

git clean -fdX     # Does nothing
```

Why is it not removing `folder1/folder2/`?

[The docs say](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) that

- `**/foo` matches file or directory `foo` anywhere, the same as pattern `foo`

so my `folder2/` pattern does match `/folder1/folder2/` and `-X` should clean it.

What's going on?

Comment: You should add `touch folder1/a` to your test setup, otherwise it removes `folder1`.

Comment: Seems that this has something to do with `git`'s lack of “directory” concept. At least for me it removes the whole `folder1`. But if I `touch folder1/a` it doesn't remove anything. After I `git add folder1/a` it removes `folder2` as expected.

Comment: To sum up, seems to be a bug (or, at least, improper documentation).

Comment: yes, if e.g. `folder1/folder2/file` is created as a build product and ignored, the I would expect `git clean -dX` to remove it if `folder2/` is in `.gitignore`. So either this is correct behaviour with wrong/confusing documentation, or incorrect behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Git are you using?  You may have run into this bug: [Bug: git ls-files and ignored directories](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/198795).

This bug was [fixed](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/commit/?id=eb41775ecc031cd8e38aebbd26826d74922a0db9) in v1.7.11.2.  From the [release notes](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.11.2.txt):

> - "`git ls-files --exclude=t -i`" did not consider anything under `t/` as excluded, as it did not pay attention to exclusion of leading paths while walking the index.  Other two users of `excluded()` are also updated.

Comment: Everything I described in the comments to this question was on 1.8.1.5.

Comment: I was using git 1.7.9.5. While using 1.8.2.1 does make a difference in my example script (it would clean `folder1`), it doesn't make a difference if I `touch folder1/file`, so the original problem of not removing `folder2` persists.